# Change Window Frame Color For Regedit, GVim, and other windows

Tags: windows, vim, windows-registry, colors

I have been able to change many of the Window Frame colors to black using the following key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors
```

and setting:

```
WindowFrame 1 0 0
```

However, this does not affect many of the windows such as the ones in GVim, Regedit, and others.

Also, I can't seem to figure out how to set it for inactive windows (which seem to get set automatically to some function of the WindowFrame color).

Interestingly, setting WindowFrame to 0 0 0, did not work.  (For some reason, Windows 10 seems to special case 0 to no change or maybe 255 255 255.)

Also, if there is a way to change the Frame color on a specific application, that would be handy as well.

Here is a link to "How to Enable and Customize Window Border and Title Bar Color on Windows 10", that was the closest thing I've found so far:

https://thegeekpage.com/customize-window-border-and-title-bar-color/

I am trying to create a night mode, but personalization, other display links, and the regedit do not seem to provide a way to get rid of many windows all white and therefor distracting frames while in my "night-time" mode.

This most similar question I could find was this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889977/where-in-registry-is-windows-titlebar-color-when-accent-color-is-not-switched-on

This question does address the inactive color, but the explanation is not consistent with what I am experiencing when I change it.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Show colour on Start, action center and title bar from Settings App. Goto HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM and set ColorPrevalence to 1 and AccentColor to 171717. Optionally, create new -> DWORD (32-bit), name it AccentColorInactive (credits) and set it to 444444 to have coloured inactive titlebar too. All the numbers are hex codes that you can change according to your taste.